# R stringR RegExp strategy for grouping like expressions without prior knowledge

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I've got a list of 50K+ part numbers. I need to group them by their Product Type. Part numbers are typically near each other in sequence, although they're not perfectly sequential. The product description is always similar, but does not follow optimum rules. Let me illustrate with the following table.

```
| PartNo | Description | ProductType |
|--------|-------------|-------------|
|A000443 |Water Bottle |    Water    |
|A000445 |Contain Water|    Water    |
|A000448 |WaterBotHold |    Water    |
|HRZ55   |Hershey_Bar  | Energy Bar  |
|RRB55   |Candy Energy | Energy Bar  |
|QMU55   |Bar Protein  | Energy Bar  |
```

I do not know the Product Types before hand. The stringR regular expression has to be smart enough to generate a product type from the parts description. I'm a rookie just making my way through *R for Data Science* and this seems achievable, although difficult.

How would you go about even starting this problem? What I'm actually working with is shown below. The expectation is that my stringR syntax will populate the ProductType column.

```
| PartNo | Description | ProductType |
|--------|-------------|-------------|
|A000443 |Water Bottle |             |
|A000445 |Contain Water|             |
|A000448 |WaterBotHold |             |
|HRZ55   |Hershey_Bar  |             |
|RRB55   |Candy Energy |             |
|QMU55   |Bar Protein  |             |
```

Here's the reproducible example to get the ball rolling.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- tribble(
  ~PartNo, ~Description, ~ProductType, 
  "A000443", "Water Bottle", "",
  "A000445", "Contain Water", "",
  "A000448", "WaterBotHold", "",
  "HRZ55", "Hershey_Bar", "",
  "RRB55", "Candy Energy", "",
  "QMU55", "Bar Protein", ""
)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Is it literally to parse the product names into types? That sounds like rather advanced natural language processing. You say you "don't know" product types, so does that mean you can invent your own?

Comment: Yes, I need to parse the product names into types. For the first three line items, is it trivial for stringR to recognize there is a word that repeats, that word happens to be water, and stringR should then use this as a *ProductType* category to populate the third column. There's no way I can manually create these *ProductType* for 50K line items, so I need some automated method. The part numbers and descriptions often resemble each other somehow or other and this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: OK, so in general is that a strategy? Or how are you going to compute that the next 3 items are energy bars? What if you get a "chocolate bar", is that going to be an energy bar or would you create a different category?

Comment: What you're really describing is a machine learning problem, not regular expressions. If you had thousands of examples of product records with the correct Product Types populated you might be able to run the single character tokenized part numbers and tokenized descriptions into a [word2vec](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html) model and then use [gradient boosting](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm.html) to try and make predictions, but that may not even give you reliable results if those are the only two fields you have.

Comment: Maybe I should have left the 4th, 5th and 6th line items off. Although those are actual entries, they probably make my problem unsolvable for the reasons you state. While I do think that generating a regular expressions for lines 1,2 and 3 is achievable. Should I repost with only the first three line items at this point? Or leave this up? Not sure about StackOverflow rules/etiquette for this type of situation.

Comment: maybe you should rather show much more rows, so that we could think about a strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `stringr::str_extract`. It works for multiple words which are separated by `|`.

**Updated:**

OP suggested that words to look up as `ProductType` is not known and those should be decided on basis of frequency of different words in `Description` column.

An option is to use `qdap` package to find frequencies of different words and select top `n` (say 2) words which will decide product type. The solution will be as:

```
library(stringr)
library(qdap)

#Find frequencies of different words
freq <- freq_terms(df$Description)

#Select top `n`. I have taken top 2 and create regex pattern 
word_to_search <- paste0(freq$WORD[1:2],collapse = "|")

df$ProductType <- str_extract(tolower(df$Description), word_to_search)
df
#    PartNo   Description ProductType
# 1 A000443  Water Bottle       water
# 2 A000445 Contain Water       water
# 3 A000448  WaterBotHold       water
# 4   HRZ55   Hershey_Bar         bar
# 5   RRB55  Candy Energy        <NA>    #Didn't match with Water/Bar
# 6   QMU55   Bar Protein         bar
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"PartNo  Description 
A000443 'Water Bottle' 
A000445 'Contain Water'
A000448 WaterBotHold 
HRZ55   Hershey_Bar  
RRB55   'Candy Energy' 
QMU55   'Bar Protein'",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you. The only issue with this is that I don't know that the product type `Water` or `Bar` even exist. The stringR expression has to notice these words repeat line item to line item, and pick them out of this Description column.

Comment: @stackinator The problem is that you cannot even consider on the basis of repetition. For example, word like `Energy` etc could be repeated too. Even repetition of text like `Bottle` cannot be ruled out.

Comment: @stackinator One option is to use `qdap` package to find frequencies of different words in `description` column. You can then select top 2 words and prepare `pattern` to be used in `str_extract`. I have updated my answer now. Have a look.