# regular expression to extract repeating word with R stringR

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I've got a list of 50K+ part numbers. I need to group them by their Product Type. Part numbers are typically near each other in sequence, although they're not perfectly sequential. The product description is always similar, but does not follow rules. Let me illustrate with the following table.

```
| PartNo | Description | ProductType |
|--------|-------------|-------------|
|A000443 |Water Bottle |    Water    |
|A000445 |Contain Water|    Water    |
|A000448 |WaterBotHold |    Water    |
```

I do not know the Product Types before hand. The stringR regular expression has to be smart enough to generate a product type from the parts description. I imagine the strategy is to look for a repeating word, and then pull it out, mutate it into column *ProductType*.

How would you go about even starting this problem? What I'm actually working with is shown below. The expectation is that my stringR syntax will populate the ProductType column.

```
| PartNo | Description | ProductType |
|--------|-------------|-------------|
|A000443 |Water Bottle |             |
|A000445 |Contain Water|             |
|A000448 |WaterBotHold |             |
```

Here's the reproducible example to get the ball rolling.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- tribble(
  ~PartNo, ~Description, ~ProductType, 
  "A000443", "Water Bottle", "",
  "A000445", "Contain Water", "",
  "A000448", "WaterBotHold", ""
)
```

Comment: Yes I need to close this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281816/r-stringr-regexp-strategy-for-grouping-like-expressions-without-prior-knowledge) but I don't have enough votes.

Comment: I think this is beyond the power of regex to solve. This sounds more like a machine learning classification problem.

Comment: And there is an SE forum for machine learning.

Comment: Yeah, a regex can't do this. What you need is some statistical analysis of words in the text that can produce a list in descending order of those that appear most frequently. Then you need to match each product description against the highest-placed word on the frequency table, and use that word for the type. Even so, you'll probably get some garbage. You'll probably have to insert spaces first in word groups like "WaterBotHold", based on inserting a space before an upper-case letter.